# How can I set an expression to the File mask input on Foreach loop enumerator in SSIS 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, expression

This question has been answered for SSIS 2012 in [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256066/how-can-i-set-an-expression-to-the-filespec-property-on-foreach-file-enumerator), but because SSIS 2008 doesn't have the Expression Task I don't know how to solve it.

**How can i set an expression to the File input on Foreach loop enumerator in SSIS 2008 that will filter all filenames that consist of numbers and end with .jpg and/or end with _number.jpg?**

Background info: In SSIS 2008 I have a foreach loop that will store the filename into a variable for all jpg files. The enumorator configuration for Files is currently: `*.jpg` This will handle all jpg files.

What is the code so it will only handle names likes?:

```
3417761506233.jpg
3417761506233_1.jpg
5414233177487.jpg
5414233177487_1.jpg
5414233177487_14.jpg
```

but not names like:

```
abc.jpg
abc123.jpg
def.png
456.png
```

The numbers represent EAN codes by the way. In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198592/regex-code-how-to-filter-all-names-that-contain-only-numbers-and-end-with-jpg-a) I thought this could be done with a RegEx ^\d+(_\d+)?.jpg$, but this keeps returning an error stating no files can be found. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-regular-expression-file-filter-ssis-sean-werick/ 
Link has a long, but very good explanation of how to do this for other users who have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the Expressions on your file enumerator (at the top), you will want to assign your Variable into the `FileSpec` property

[image]

Comment: Thank you @billinkc, so using the Expressions inside the foreach loop would be the same as separate Expression Task in SSIS2012? But what code should I put in? The one you mentioned in your image will return all .jpg files, but I have more restrictions mentioned in the question.